# How to change style in a Leaflet's imageOverlay apart from opacity?

Tags: leaflet

I would like to change the style of an ImageOverlay in Leaflet. As I saw from the imageOverlay instance apart from `setUrl`, `setBounds`, `setOpacity` methods there seems to be a `setStyle` method which only seems to work with opacity or with limited css attributes.
f.i

```
imageOverlay.setStyle({
    opacity: 0.5
})
```

this works fine as expected.

For instance how would I change the `borderColor` or `color` or `fill` properties? I have used

```
imageOverlay.setStyle({
   borderColor: '#FF0000 blue'
})
```

but no style is applied.

Below I give an example. I have two buttons implementing two functions. SetOpacity that works fine and setBorderColor that does not work.

Any recommendations are welcome.

```css
#mapid {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.4.0/leaflet.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.4.0/leaflet.js"></script>

<button onclick='setOverlayOpacity()'>ChangeOpacity</button>

<button onclick='setOverlayBorderColor()'>Change Border Color</button>

<div id="mapid"></div>

<script>
  var map = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(map);

  var imageUrl = 'http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
    imageBounds = [
      [40.712216, -74.22655],
      [40.773941, -74.12544]
    ];
  var imageOverlay = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);

  console.log(imageOverlay)

  map.fitBounds(imageBounds)

  function setOverlayOpacity() {
    imageOverlay.setStyle({
      opacity: 0.5
    })
  }

  function setOverlayBorderColor() {
    imageOverlay.setStyle({
      borderColor: '#FF0000 blue'
    })
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setStyle()` method of `L.ImageOverlay` is [not documented](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#imageoverlay) on purpose, and only for compatibility for [`L.FeatureGroup.setStyle()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#featuregroup-setstyle), which is mainly meant for setting style options for `L.Path`, *not* CSS rules.

In fact, the [current implementation of `L.ImageOverlay.setStyle()` method](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/ada86aaf68ec8c047c2aacc2476c8fc00096a2cb/src/layer/ImageOverlay.js#L102) only sets the opacity:

```
setStyle: function (styleOpts) {
    if (styleOpts.opacity) {
        this.setOpacity(styleOpts.opacity);
    }
    return this;
},
```

I think that what you want to do is to use [`L.ImageOverlay.getElement()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#imageoverlay-getelement), which returns a [`HTMLImageElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) and then access its [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property, e.g.:

```
myOverlay.getElement().style.border = '2px solid red';
```

Alternatively, use the [`className` option](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#imageoverlay-classname) to assign a CSS class to the `ImageOverlay`'s `HTMLImageElement`, and add CSS rules accordingly.